# How to assign tensor values to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

There are ways to initialize tensor with a numpy array. But is there any way to do the opposite. Meaning initialize a numpy array with a tensor in the graph.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to evaluate the tensor under a session. Assume you have a tensor `t` defined as

```
x = tf.Variable(...)
y = tf.Variable(...)

t = tf.add(x, y)
```

and you want to know its value (given the current `x` and `y`).
You then just use a session to fetch it:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    numpy_array = sess.run(t)
```

or, equivalently,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    numpy_array = t.eval(sess)
```

That should be all there is to it.