# How to get a tensorflow op by name?

Tags: python, tensorflow

You can get a tensor by name with `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("tensor_name:0")`

But can you get an operation, such as `Optimizer.minimize`, or an `enqueue` operation on a queue?

In my first model I returned all tensors and ops I would need from a `build_model` function. But the list of tensors got ugly. In later models I tossed all tensors and ops in a dictionary for easier access. This time around I thought I'd just look up tensors by name as I needed them, but I don't know how to do that with ops.

Or is there a better way to do this? I find various tensors and ops are needed all over the place. Training, inference code, test cases, hence the desire for a nice standard way of accessing the various parts of the graph without passing variables all over the place.

Comment: It would be really nice if there was a more standardized and less verbose way to get tensors and ops out of the graph. I also have gone through the stages of passing everything around as arguments and putting everything in dictionaries. Both have downsides.

Comment: Agreed, in my latest work I encapsulated the model structure in a class and all tensors and ops became model.mytensor or m.mytensor. Except for suppressing warning messages it seems to be convenient so far.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name) method to get a `tf.Operation` by name. For example, to get an operation called `"enqueue"` from the default graph:

```
op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("enqueue")
```