# using saved model to make prections in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

i have this code to train a restore a model in tensorflow . but how can I make predictions.

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction=neural_network_model(x)
    cost=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = prediction, labels = y)
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            #while i < len(train_x):
            t = len(train_x)
            f = t%batch_size
            while i < (t-f):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])


                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                #epoch_loss = epoch_loss + c
                i+=batch_size
                #i = i + batch_size
            print('Epoch =', epoch+1, '/',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        save_path = saver.save(sess, "sesionestensorflow/model1.ckpt")
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)


        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))
```

i see this answer but i can`t make the prediction. 
[Using saved model for prediction in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902400/using-saved-model-for-prediction-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create an empy graph, define the network, load the saved weights and thus run inference.

```
prediction = tf.argmax(neural_network_model(x), 1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # load the trained weights into the model
    saver.restore(sess, "sesionestensorflow/model1.ckpt")
    # just use the model
    out = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: <your input> })
```

Comment: ok, the result is this, but i expect  a zero array with one number 1 . feed dict = [[ 0.6737      0.6737      0.6737     41.606056   16.11666667]]
out [[   62.6507  -2025.7719    136.06538 -2349.9055  -4071.8032  -1727.9988
     78.84228  -305.2752  -1380.6096    299.88174  1483.1726   1353.7816
   2282.4849   1986.554    2496.1821 ]]

Comment: Because prediction is the output of your model. You're looking for the class with the higher probability. I update the answer