# How to restore a saved tensorflow model?

Tags: save, restore

There are two python files, The first one is for saving the tensorflow
model. The second one is for restoring the saved model.

**Question：**

1. When I run the two files one after another, it's ok.
2. When I run the first one, restart the edit and run the second one,it
   tells me that the w1 is not defined?

**What I want to do is:**

1. Save a tensorflow model
2. Restore the saved model

What's wrong with it? Thanks for your kindly help?

**model_save.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2]), name='w1')
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[5]), name='w2')
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess: 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(sess, 'SR\\my-model')
```

**model_restore.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:    
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('SR\\my-model.meta')
saver.restore(sess,'SR\\my-model')
print (sess.run(w1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, you should use

```
print (sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w1:0')))
```

instead of `print (sess.run(w1))` in your **model_restore.py** file.

**model_save.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
w1_node = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2]), name='w1')
w2_node = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[5]), name='w2')
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(w1_node.eval()) # [ 0.43350926  1.02784836]
  #print(w1.eval()) # NameError: name 'w1' is not defined
  saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

`w1_node` is only defined in **model_save.py**, and **model_restore.py** file can't recognize it.
When we call a `Tensor` variable by its `name`, we should use `get_tensor_by_name`, as this post [Tensorflow: How to get a tensor by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name) suggested.

**model_restore.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model.meta')
  saver.restore(sess,'my-model')
  print (sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w1:0')))
  # [ 0.43350926  1.02784836]
  print(tf.global_variables()) # print tensor variables
  # [<tf.Variable 'w1:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>,
  #  <tf.Variable 'w2:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32_ref>]
  for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print str(op.name) # print all the operation nodes' name
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer.
According to your suggestion and relevant references,
I have just solved the problem：）