# TensorFlow: get_variable() but for placeholders?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a function `tf.get_variable('name')` which allows to "implicitly" pass parameters into function like:

```
def function(sess, feed):
    with tf.variable_scope('training', reuse=True):
        cost = tf.get_variable('cost')
    value = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed) 
    # other statements
```

But what if one want to pass a `tf.placeholder` into function? Is there same mechanism for placeholders, i.e. something like `tf.get_placeholder()`:

```
def function(sess, cost, X_train, y_train):
    # Note this is NOT a valid TF code
    with tf.variable_scope('training', reuse=True):
        features = tf.get_placeholder('features')
        labels = tf.get_placeholder('labels')
    feed = {features: X_train, labels: y_train}
    value = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed)
    print('Cost: %s' % value)
```

Or it doesn't make too much sense to do it and better to just construct placeholders inside of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders are just... placeholders. It's pointless "getting" a placeholder as if it has some sort of state (that's what get variable does, returns a variable in its current state).

Just use the same python variable everywhere.

Also, if you don't want to pass a python variable because your method signaturl becomes ugly, you can exploit the fact that you're building a graph and the graph itself contains the information about the declared placeholders.

You can do something like:

```
#define your placeholder
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="asd")

# then, when you need it, fetch if from the graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("asd:0")
```

Comment: Ok, got it. So basically, placeholder is kind of "stateless" and creating new ones doesn't introduce any overhead, right?

Comment: Yes. The overhead is introduced only when you use it, because of the data transfer from python to tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

Aside the fact that if you are working in the same script you should not need this, you can do that by getting the tensor by name, as in [Tensorflow: How to get a tensor by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name)

For instance

```
p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
p2 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(p.name)

assert p == p2
```

Comment: I see, great, thank you. By the way, do you know why the variable has name like `loss/loss:0` installed of just `loss`?

Comment: this explains it somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors