# how tf.constant selected by name like tf.get_variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
with g1.as_default() :
    with tf.variable_scope("testa") :
        tf.get_variable(name = "a", shape = [1], dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.ones_initializer )
        tf.constant( value = [1], dtype = tf.float32, name = "b" )
```

we can use the attribute `name` of `tf.get_variable` to select the variable in the tensorflow at any places. for example, in the image, we can use `tf.get_variable("a")` to get variable in the graph `g`. How can we use the same or similar method to get the constant `"b"`?

Comment: Can you post your code as text inside the question please? Do not upload images.

Comment: @Jingyao Moved the code from the image to the question

Comment: You could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name) for some details related to your question.

Comment: thanks, the api tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("name") really solves the problem