# What is the canonical way of getting a tensor by name in Tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name), in Tensorflow v1 you could retrieve a tensor or operation output via its Graph within a session:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ...
    tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("example:0")
```

In Tensorflow 2 [direct use of the graph is deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#using_graphs_directly_deprecated), and thus not the preferred approach.

The `get_tensor_by_name` method still exists, but to get the  implicit graph you would have to call something like `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()`, which essentially is a way of making TF1 code work in TF2.

Is there some canonical way in Tensorflow 2 of retrieving a tensor which exists in the implicit computation graph, but which you do not have any reference to except for by name?

Comment: Name based variable access is highly discouraged in TF2 and most likely there is another way to achieve what you want. Are you looking to retrieve a tensor which is a layer weight or input traveling through the network? Are you using the `tf.keras` API?

Comment: @bluesummers Yes, I am using the tf.keras API. Specifically, I would like to access a tensor defined within the optimizer for logging purposes without having to edit the optimizer code.

Comment: Great, then we are one step closer to solution; every optimizer has a `.get_weights()` method - is that what you are looking for? Since we are not accessing by name, the specifics of what you are trying to access is critical to find a solution, so if you can share what exactly you are looking for I might be able to help

Comment: Also, if the `.get_weights()` is not what you are looking for, try `.get_slots_names()` followed by `.get_slot()` where you can access other variables that the optimizer uses. A third way is using `.variables()`... Essentially you have access to anything, it depends on what you are trying to achieve